# How do change the keyboard layout when the unlock keyring dialog is in focus?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-keyring

This is an annoying issue, that should probably be considered as feature request.

Today when I logged into the machine the keyboard layout was in Hebrew, and I was asked to type in my keyring password. Because the layout was Hebrew I couldn't type my keyring password. On the other hand, the keyring prevented me from changing my keyboard layout. Is there a way for me to maintain some activity of my keyboard layout? A related issue is that the keyboard layout prevents me from accessing my Bluetooh connection which might be an issue because I have a Bleutooth keyboard that I might need to reconnect.

If anyone is here because they have had the same issue, I had to edit `/etc/default/keyboard/` from terminal (`ctrl+alt+F3`) and left only the English layout. This is far a from ideal solution.

Comment: You can have both in `/etc/default/keyboard` if you let English be the first one.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm fairly certain that English was the first one (right after booting), but I'll have to check once I'm back home. My machine is configured to have a different layout for each window. Can it be related?

Comment: I've tested it again, and everything seemed fine. I'm certain that English was the first option in the keyboard file. I think that being able to change the keyboard layout while the keyring dialog is a crucial issue. Where should I report this feature request/bug?

Comment: I think it's [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1286910).